# Очередность вхождения элементов (hover в html)

Tags: html, css

Есть код: `#nav td:hover p{}` который говорит, что если навести мышку на td, то с p-шкой что-то будет, а как прописать, что если p-шки идут друг за другом и с ними надо сделать общее действие? Есть вариант, что обернуть во что-то типа класса, но пока почему-то не прокатывает...

```
<tr>
<td>
    <a href="#">Отдел продаж</a>
    <p title="Описание работы отдела продаж в г. Тамбов">
        <span>
            <p>За каждым Клиентом Компании закрепляется персональный менеджер, в функции которого входит:</p>
            <p>
                - компетентные консультации по любому типу тары и упаковки; - предоставление бесплатных образцов любой продукции; - формирование оптимального индивидуального ассортиментно- ценового предложения; - предоставление наиболее удобных схем сотрудничества, заключение договора и дополнительных соглашений; - резервирование по запросу Клиента необходимого объема товара; - сопровождение любых заказов Клиента, от получения заявки до контроля непосредственной разгрузки товара.
                <!-- <span><a href="#">Связь с отделом продаж</a></span>-->
            </p>
        </span>
</td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Приписать для каждой p свой класс и задавать его в виде, например:

```
td:hover p.class_1
td:hover p.class_2
```

Answer (score 0):

Вам пока не с отделом продаж нужно связываться, а выучить какие элементы в какие можно вкладывать. <p> в <span> вставлять нельзя, <p> в <p> тоже, тэги надо закрывать.